# Merge policy control Apollo Client

Tags: apollo, apollo-client, react-apollo

Is there any way to tell apollo to call merge policy only after using fetchMore method? I'm using it to implement infinite scroll and stick existing and incoming data together which works perfectly for me. But when I'm using writeQuery method to change my cache manually, merge policy executes after that operation too and this cause duplicate data.

Answer (score 0):

You have access to the variables in the merge function.

if the `fetchMore` has a specific pagination variable that the `writeQuery` has not you can decide to concatenate the incoming results only for the `fetchMore`:

For example, if the `fetchMore` uses a nextToken variable:

```
typePolicies: {
      Query: {
        fields: {
          myQuery: {
            keyArgs: false,
            merge: (existing = [], incoming = [], { args }) => {
              if (args?.nextToken === undefined) return incoming
              return [...existing, ...incoming]
            }
          },
```